# how do I initialize a std::map in the base member initialization section in c++?

Tags: c++, initialization-list

Basically I have a map as a member variable in a class that I would like to initialize with key,value pairs in the base member initialization section.

```
Parser::Parser()
    :operations() //the dictionary
{

}
```

I'm not quite sure what the syntax is for doing this. I was thinking something like:

```
Parser::Parser()
    :operations({"hello","goodbye"},{"foo","bar"}) 
{

}
```

but that's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an initializer list:

```
Parser::Parser()
    :operations({{"hello","goodbye"},{"foo","bar"}}) 
{

}
```

This should work as well:

```
Parser::Parser()
    :operations{{"hello","goodbye"},{"foo","bar"}}
{

}
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/ouA1Aj).

*Edit*: this is an alternative that should work under VS:

```
struct a {
    std::map<int, int> x;

    static std::map<int, int> make_map() {
        std::map<int, int> some_map = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
        return some_map;
    }

    a() : x(make_map()) {}
};
```

Comment: it it doesn't like either of those. It keeps saying ';' expected

Comment: Are you using C++11? I've added a demo to my answer.

Comment: Yes I'm using C++11 in Visual Studio 2012. That website is neat! Never seen that. But yeah I'm not sure what's the issue. I pasted exactly what you put in your demo into a blank c++ project and it had the same missing ';' error.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time. Any alternative ways of doing this? My prof is strict and we have to use Visual Studio and initialize in base member section

Comment: @thed0ctor MSVC did not adopt initializer lists until the [November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515). More info on current adoption of C++11 features by various vendors [can be found here](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport). I suggest you install that, then switch the project you're working with to use the CTP toolchain. The config to do so is on the main Properties page of your project (and don't forget to change both Debug *and* Release builds.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh yeah, I forgot it took them ages to implement them :S.

Comment: @mfontanini, I used your alternative and it didn't like the brackets, I then played around with using parenthesis and it accepted this syntax: `the_map = ((1,2),(3,4));`, I then tried using this same syntax in the initializer list and it worked. I have edited my post to reflect this